# Unable to create new build configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, buildconfiguration

Here's an annoying one.

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 that contains a .Net 4.5 class library, a .NET 4.5 web application and a .NET 4.5 website.

I want to create a new build configuration, let's call it Publish or Live, mainly so that I can select it when publishing the web application and use a web.config transform.

So I click my Solution, go to Build then Configuration Manager. In the configuration dropdown, I choose , and I get the little popup asking me for the name of the new configuration etc. I fill this in, click OK, and......nothing. Nada.

No matter what I call the new configuration, whether I choose to copy from an existing configuration etc, no new configuration is created. Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: when you create a new build config it is added to the config. is it in the combo ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, but when I deselected 'create new project configurations', I was able to create a new solution configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem. I figured out that VS 2019 doesn't like it to have projects grouped in an project folder (virtual folder) which is named the same way as the project is. Or where the "virtual" folder name has the same name as an actual project

Example:

(virtual) project folder name: CompanyName.Webservice
Content: CompanyName.Webservice (from CompanyName.Webservice.csproj)

In that case I couldn't neither add or rename project configurations nor execute transformation of web.config files of that project

Hope that helps someone after so many years...

Comment: Had the same issue with a SSAS project. Project folder had same name as project, and could not create new configuration. The name in the configuration manager showed the project as  ProjectX\ProjectX. After renaming virtual folder the conf. man. showed as ProjectX

Comment: Thanks, but this is so dumb!

Answer (score -3):

If you cannot find solution configuration settings on the Standard toolbar or cannot access the Configuration Manager, you may have Visual Basic developer settings applied. For more information, see How to: Manage Build Configurations with Visual Basic Developer Settings Applied.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx

Solution :

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165414.aspx

Comment: If you read carefully, the problem is not accessing the configuration manager, but rather that it is not saving the new settings.